# Azure: How to create a service reference to an internal endpoint

Tags: c#, windows, azure

How can I create a Service Reference from a Web Role to a Worker Role with an internal endpoint implementing a WCF host?

Comment: Internal means only visible in the Azure CloudService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have 2 options here:

1. Use a share DLL instead of using a service reference ([basic concept is explained here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/juveriak/archive/2008/02/03/using-channels-vs-proxies-in-wcf.aspx))
2. Create WCF service:

   - Create a assembly for your contract + service (ideally you might also want to separate the contract from the implementation)
   - Reference this assembly in your worker
   - Create a 'dummy' WCF application referencing your newly created assembly which only contains a *.svc file with the following code (you won't deploy this service, it's only goal is to allow using a service reference).

---

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyWorker.Service.ContactService" %>
```

- In your WebRole, add a service reference and VS will discover the service in the dummy WCF application.

  (you can do the same with svcutil.exe)

[image]